# How to parse /proc/pid/stat?

Tags: rust, procfs

I'm writing a program to parse data from `/proc/pid/stat`, but don't know how to parse those fields using idiomatic rust. The second field can contain anything, including space and parenthesis.

`/proc/pid/stat` look like this:

```
802359 (cat) R 728674 802359 728674 34824 802359 4194304 92 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 10550623 11358208 132 18446744073709551615 94492582699008 94492582716465 140732240338192 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 7 0 0 0 0 0 94492582734480 94492582736064 94492600344576 140732240341139 140732240341159 140732240341159 140732240343019 0
```

Comment: Given that the second field starts with `(` and ends with `)`, and that there can be no parentheses in the other fields, just use [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) and [`rfind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.rfind) to find the boundaries of the second field, and [`split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) to parse the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let s = "802359 (cat foo bar) R 728674 802359 728674 34824 802359 4194304 92 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 10550623 11358208 132 18446744073709551615 94492582699008 94492582716465 140732240338192 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 7 0 0 0 0 0 94492582734480 94492582736064 94492600344576 140732240341139 140732240341159 140732240341159 140732240343019 0";
let field2 = s
    .chars()
    .skip_while(|&x| x != '(')
    .take_while(|&x| x != ')')
    .collect::<String>()
    + ")";
println!("{:?}", field2);
```

You can do something similar with [split_ascii_whitespace()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_ascii_whitespace) instead of [chars()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) to parse the whole string.

Comment: The second field can contain ')' so your code can product wrong result. I think find and rfind should do it, as @Jmb pointed out.